# Replicate object and field data that you see when defining a custom button

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, custom-button, package

Administrator needs to identify how and where they want to store their files in SALESFORCE CONTENT MANAGEMENT. What this means is that when a user loads a specific record (eg they load the Account), then in SALESFORCE CONTENT MANAGEMENT, we create a unique folder for the record where their files can be stored. In order to do this, we allow the admin to define a configuration for each object like an Account, Opportunity, or any other custom object.

What then happens is that the user launches a custom action for a given object that generates a document and then creates in the folder associated with that record. In order to do this, they create a custom Salesforce button and paste in a url that we generate for the administrator.

A couple examples of where this falls down is how we refer to the Account Name when working on an account. We are using an Api that provides us Opportunity.Account.Name; however, when I go to the custom button, it does not recognize this and wants us to use Account.Name.

A similar scenario occurs when i use the Account.Owner.Name. When creating a custom button, it requires that I user Account.OwnerFullName.

What I want to do is expose in our admin ui, the representation of the object in accordance with how the custom button requires. How do I do this?